# CoAP.NET for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, coap

My project need to use CoAP.NET. But after adding CoAP.NET in PCL, the Android or iOS project will report an error like this when building. 
"Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Common.Logging, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?"

It seems like that it does not support common.logging library, cause i add that in all parts of the solution, and it cannot be added. Although, the common.logging.core can be added.

In iOS Project I choose the Linker behaviour to "Don't Link", and it can be builded. But in Android project, it won't work.

Does Xamarin work with CoAP.NET? If Not, how to use CoAP?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean this [library](https://github.com/smeshlink/CoAP.NET/tree/master/CoAP.NET)?  It appears to include an iOS version of the library, but not one for Android.  You can either try to build the source yourself as an Android (or PCL) library, fixing any issues you find, or you could contact the author and ask them about Android support.

If you can find a native Android (Java) implementation, you could also created a [binding library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/) for it that would allow you to use it from Xamarin.